# An efficient way to get and store the shortest paths

Tags: java

When I say efficient I mean code that isn't cpu intensive.

**The Problem:**
I have a field of blocks. Like in the following image:

[image: Image of a 10 by 10 field of blocks]

Every single one of these blocks represents an instance of a self-made `Block` class. This block class has a `List<Block> neighBours`, where the neighbours of the block are stored. So every single block in the image knows which blocks are next to it.

What I want to do is to pick any block from this image, and compute how many "steps" away this block is. For example if I pick the block in the top left, I want to have a `Map<Block, Integer>` representing how many "steps" away each block is from the picked block. Like this:

[image: Image of a 10 by 10 field of blocks with numbers in it]

Now before you say "Just store it's position X and Y in the block class and calculate the difference X + difference Y", that wouldn't work because the field can have gaps(represented by red color) between them like the following image:

[image: Image of a 10 by 10 field of blocks with numbers in it]

And as you might notice, the block next to the gap that was first 4 steps away, is now 6 steps away. Thus the best way(I presume) to get how many steps away the other blocks are is by using a recursive algorith that makes use of the neighbour info. I couldn't make an efficient one myself and I was hoping someone might know something that works well.

Several problems I came across are the fact that because all blocks know their neighbours, the recursive algorithm would go indefinately back and forth between the first and second block. Or the fact that when using the algorithm on a 11x11 field, there were 3284 method calls, which seems waaay too high for an 11x11 field.

**Question:**
So the question I have is: What is an efficient way, using the knowledge of what neighbours each block has, to get how many steps away each block is.

**Code:**
This is the current code that I have incase anyone wants to see it.

```
public class Block
{
    List<Block> neighBours;
    public Block(List<Block> neighBours)
    {
        this.neighBours = neighBours;
    }
    public Map<Block, Integer> getStepsAway()
    {
        Map<Block, Integer> path = new HashMap<Block, Integer>();
        getPaths(path, 0, 100);
        return path;
    }
    public void getPaths(Map<Block, Integer> path, int pathNumber, int maxPathNumber)
    {           
        if(pathNumber <= maxPathNumber)
        {
            for(Block block : neighBours)
            {
                Integer thePathNumber = path.get(block);
                if(thePathNumber != null)
                {
                    if(pathNumber < thePathNumber)
                    {
                        path.put(block, pathNumber);
                        block.getPaths(path, pathNumber + 1, maxPathNumber);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    path.put(block, pathNumber);
                    block.getPaths(path, pathNumber + 1, maxPathNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem looks a bit like path finding. You maybe could check out the A* algorithm.

Comment: This [page](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html) exactly describes your problem, the empty spaces are akin to obstacles talked in that page.

Comment: Check my answer, which will result in much better performance than applying A* multiple times, and will be pretty straightforward to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive algorithms are doomed to fail on a large grid. Java is not designed for deep recursions and can only withstand a few thousands recursive calls before failing with a `StackOverflowException`. Only iterative solutions are a reasonible approach for large pathfinding problems in Java.

Of course you can always use a classic pathfinding algorithm such as A*, but you would have to apply it for each cell, which would be extremely expensive.

Indeed, your problem is a bit particular in the sense you want to calculate the minimum distance to **all** cells and not only just one. Therefore, you can do it in a more clever way.

One property of your problem is that given `A` and `B`, if the minimal path from `A` to `B` contains `C` then this path is also minimal from `A` to `C` and from `C` to `B`. That's what my intuition tells me, but it would need to be proven before implementing my suggestion.

The algorithm I propose is efficient, uses `O(n)` memory and has `O(n^2)` runtime complexity (cannot be faster since you need to set this many cells in the array):

- start with your first point and set the distance of all its valid neighbours to `1`. Doing so, you will record the *border*, which is all the cells at distance `1` from the first cell.
- then, you iterate over the border and take all their neighbours which have not already been assigned a distance and assign them distance `2`. All cells of distance `2` become your new border.
- iterate until the border is empty

Below is a full working solution. The code may be improved in various ways using more convenience methods for initializing and printing matrices of objects and primitive integers, but you get the idea:

```
public class Solution {
    public enum Cell { FREE, BLOCKED }

    // assuming cells is a rectangular array with non-empty columns
    public static int[][] distances(Cell[][] cells, ArrayCoordinate startingPoint) {
        int[][] distances = new int[cells.length][cells[0].length];
        // -1 will mean that the cell is unreachable from the startingPoint
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++) {
                distances[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        distances[startingPoint.i][startingPoint.j] = 0;

        Set<ArrayCoordinate> border = startingPoint.validNeighbours(cells);
        for (int currentDistance = 1; !border.isEmpty(); currentDistance++) {
            Set<ArrayCoordinate> newBorder = new HashSet<>();
            for (ArrayCoordinate coord : border) {
                distances[coord.i][coord.j] = currentDistance;

                for (ArrayCoordinate neighbour : coord.validNeighbours(cells)) {
                    if (distances[neighbour.i][neighbour.j] < 0) {
                        newBorder.add(neighbour);
                    }
                }
            }
            border = newBorder;
        }

        return distances;
    }

    private static class ArrayCoordinate {
        public ArrayCoordinate(int i, int j) {
            if (i < 0 || j < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array coordinates must be positive");
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }

        public final int i, j;

        public Set<ArrayCoordinate> validNeighbours(Cell[][] cells) {
            Set<ArrayCoordinate> neighbours = new HashSet<>();

            // inlining for not doing extra work in a loop iterating over (-1, 1) x (-1, 1). If diagonals are allowed
            // then switch for using a loop
            addIfValid(cells, neighbours,  1,  0);
            addIfValid(cells, neighbours, -1,  0);
            addIfValid(cells, neighbours,  0,  1);
            addIfValid(cells, neighbours,  0, -1);

            return neighbours;
        }

        private void addIfValid(Cell[][] cells, Set<ArrayCoordinate> neighbours, int dx, int dy) {
            int x = i + dx, y = j + dy;
            if (0 <= x && 0 <= y && x < cells.length && y < cells[0].length && cells[x][y] == Cell.FREE) {
                neighbours.add(new ArrayCoordinate(i + dx, j + dy));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            ArrayCoordinate point = (ArrayCoordinate) o;

            if (i != point.i) return false;
            if (j != point.j) return false;

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = i;
            result = 31 * result + j;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 11, m = 5;

        Cell[][] cells = new Cell[n][m];
        cells[1][1] = Cell.BLOCKED;
        cells[1][2] = Cell.BLOCKED;
        cells[2][1] = Cell.BLOCKED;

        ArrayCoordinate startingPoint = new ArrayCoordinate(5, 2);

        System.out.println("Initial matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++) {
                if (cells[i][j] == null) {
                    cells[i][j] = Cell.FREE;
                }
                if (startingPoint.i == i && startingPoint.j == j) {
                    System.out.print("S ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(cells[i][j] == Cell.FREE ? ". " : "X ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int[][] distances = distances(cells, startingPoint);
        System.out.println("\nDistances from starting point:");
        for (int i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < distances[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print((distances[i][j] < 0 ? "X" : distances[i][j]) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial matrix:
. . . . . 
. X X . . 
. X . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
. . S . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 
. . . . . 

Distances from starting point:
7 8 7 6 7 
6 X X 5 6 
5 X 3 4 5 
4 3 2 3 4 
3 2 1 2 3 
2 1 0 1 2 
3 2 1 2 3 
4 3 2 3 4 
5 4 3 4 5 
6 5 4 5 6 
7 6 5 6 7
```

**Bonus**

I almost cried when I saw all this boilerplate in my Java solution, so I wrote a shorter (perhaps slightly less efficient) version in Scala:

```scala
object ScalaSolution {
  sealed abstract  class Cell
  object Free    extends Cell
  object Blocked extends Cell

  // assuming cells is a rectangular array with non-empty columns
  def distances(cells: Array[Array[Cell]], startingPoint: (Int, Int)) = {
    // -1 will mean that the cell is unreachable from the startingPoint
    val distances = Array.fill[Int](cells.length, cells(0).length)(-1)
    distances(startingPoint._1)(startingPoint._2) = 0

    var (currentDistance, border) = (1, validNeighbours(cells, startingPoint))
    while (border.nonEmpty) {
      border.foreach { case (i, j) => distances(i)(j) = currentDistance }
      border = border.flatMap(validNeighbours(cells, _)).filter { case (i, j) => distances(i)(j) < 0 }
      currentDistance += 1
    }

    distances
  }

  private def validNeighbours(cells: Array[Array[Cell]], startingPoint: (Int, Int)) = {
    // inlining for not doing extra work in a for yield iterating over (-1, 1) x (-1, 1). If diagonals are allowed
    // then switch for using a for yield
    Set(neighbourIfValid(cells, startingPoint, ( 1,  0)),
        neighbourIfValid(cells, startingPoint, (-1,  0)),
        neighbourIfValid(cells, startingPoint, ( 0,  1)),
        neighbourIfValid(cells, startingPoint, ( 0, -1)))
      .flatten
  }

  private def neighbourIfValid(cells: Array[Array[Cell]], origin: (Int, Int), delta: (Int, Int)) = {
    val (x, y) = (origin._1 + delta._1, origin._2 + delta._2)
    if (0 <= x && 0 <= y && x < cells.length && y < cells(0).length && cells(x)(y) == Free) {
      Some(x, y)
    } else None
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val (n, m) = (11, 5)

    val cells: Array[Array[Cell]] = Array.fill(n, m)(Free)
    cells(1)(1) = Blocked
    cells(1)(2) = Blocked
    cells(2)(1) = Blocked

    val startingPoint = (5, 2)
    println("Initial matrix:")
    printMatrix(cells)((i, j, value) => if ((i, j) == startingPoint) "S" else if (value == Free) "." else "X")

    val distancesMatrix = distances(cells, startingPoint)
    println("\nDistances from starting point:")
    printMatrix(distancesMatrix)((i, j, value) => if (value < 0) "X" else value.toString)
  }

  private def printMatrix[T](matrix: Array[Array[T]])(formatter: (Int, Int, T) => String) = {
    for (i <- 0 until matrix.length) {
      for (j <- 0 until matrix(0).length) {
        print(formatter(i, j, matrix(i)(j)) + " ")
      }
      println()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what I wanted! I've applied it to my problem and it worked. I do however have one question that I haven't been able to figure out. I applied this to an 11 by 11 matrix(without blocked cells), made the startingPoint (5,5) and at the `newBorder.add(neighbour);` part I placed a counter. For some reason the amount of times a neighbour is added is 216. Shouldn't that amount never exceed the amount of total cells?

Comment: @JohnCake this algorithm should traverse each cell exactly one time. Could you share the code on a Gist (https://gist.github.com/) for example ?

Comment: @JohnCake just tried it mysellf, got the same thing. I have to make sense out of it

Comment: It's mostly your code with a few debugging things that helped me understand how it worked. Also I changed main to a method to be called from somewhere else. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/99d3078c45928e368d13507b28748b41

Comment: @JohnCake thanks, I'm starting to see some things I did not think about in the Java solution. I think the Scala one does not have the same issue but I first need to understand why it's doing that

Comment: @JohnCake ok, it's actually pretty trivial. It is simply the fact that in your border some cells have common neigbours. For example, `(5, 6)` is a neighbour or `(5, 5)` but also of `(6, 6)`. Therefore, if the border contains both `(5, 5)` and `(6, 6)` then `(5, 6)` is going to be added twice. This is why we are using a `Set`, to dedupe these elements. Therefore, we are indeed going to traverse the elements only once. You can see it in two different ways. The first one is to move your counter to `distances[coord.i][coord.j] = currentDistance` which is the actual place where we set elements

Comment: You should see `120` as a result since the starting point is set outside the loop. The other way to understand it is to write `if (newBorder.add(neighbour)) counter++`. `newBorder.add(neighbour)` returns `true` if and only if the element was really inserted (i.e. it was not already present in the set)

Comment: But the thing is, if a neighbour has already been set a value, it shouldn't add it again at `newBorder.add(neighbour);` because of the check in the if statement `if (distances[neighbour.i][neighbour.j] < 0) `. Right?

Comment: It's not that, it's the fact that several points of the border share the same neighbour, which is still unset. It will not really get inserted or traversed twice because the `Set` eliminates duplicates

Comment: Oh right, I see now. I completely forgot about that. That answers all my questions thanks.

Comment: @JohnCake I myself did not see right away, which I feel a bit shameful about :D. See you next time on SO

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a DP (dynamic programming) solution to this problem, looking at [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-top-left-bottom-right-nxm-matrix/), code below.  I realize this is for finding all possible paths to a cell but it can give insight on your condition about 'blanks' or 'walls'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Returns count of possible paths to reach cell at row number m and column
// number n from the topmost leftmost cell (cell at 1, 1)
int numberOfPaths(int m, int n)
{
    // Create a 2D table to store results of subproblems
    int count[m][n];

    // Count of paths to reach any cell in first column is 1
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        count[i][0] = 1;

    // Count of paths to reach any cell in first column is 1
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        count[0][j] = 1;

    // Calculate count of paths for other cells in bottom-up manner using
    // the recursive solution
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)

            // By uncommenting the last part the code calculatest he total
            // possible paths if the diagonal Movements are allowed
            count[i][j] = count[i-1][j] + count[i][j-1]; //+ count[i-1][j-1];

    }
    return count[m-1][n-1];
}
```

Comment: I think I agree it can be seen as a DP problem, but the obstacles make it not that easy because there is no sensible way to iterate over the matrix. I also think the update formula should also be modified, probably to include a `Math.min` call as well as some logic determining if the value should be incremented or decremented compared to each neighbour. Maybe I'm just being pessimistic but I think solving it as DP could be trickier than you could think at first.